# WCF Trace for single URL

Tags: wcf, trace

We have a WCF-based backend API implementation. We are dealing with a production problem, and we need to investigate just a single service erroneous behavior.
We need to get WCF Trace logs, but since the system is heavily stressed, we expect that activation for the whole application cannot be done.
What we need is to enable WCF tracing for selectively chosen URL (a single service).

We tried with the *location* element - to get the configuration applied only for particular folder/file.svc, but this does not work. Still we had to enable WCF Tracing for the whole IIS Application to get the traces generated.

Any idea how to enable WCF Tracing for a single service ?

Comment: Maybe you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921888/21567) to filter the tracing records before they are written.

Answer (score 0):

WCF tracing is built on top of System.Diagnostics. You should define trace sources in the configuration file or in code for using trace like this:

```
<configuration>  
    <system.diagnostics>  
      <sources>  
         <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"  
                    propagateActivity="true">  
            <listeners>  
               <add name="traceListener"
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                   initializeData= "c:\log\Traces.svclog" />  
            </listeners>  
         </source>  
      </sources>  
     </system.diagnostics>  
</configuration>
```

Also you can refer to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing) for further info.